# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to System.Action<int>

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I am trying to create .net standard delegate, Action with the input parameter `int`. But I am getting

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to System.Action.

I learned that same return type methods can be added to multicast delegates. Below is my code. What is the wrong with this code?  I don't see a compilation error if I write lambda expression.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action<int> AddBook = AddBookwithId(15); // Here is the error
    AddBook += x => Console.WriteLine("Added book with :{0}" , x ); // No compile error here
    AddBook += AddBookwithISBN(56434);// of course, the same error here too.
}

public static void AddBookwithId(int y)
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Added Book to the shelf with the ID : {0} ", y ); 
}

public static void AddBookwithISBN(int y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Added Book to the shelf  with the ISBN: {0} ", y + 2);
}
```

Comment: You are calling the function in the first line. The RHS of the equals sign is `AddBookwithId(15)` is a function call. The second line is adding a lambda expression. The RHS of the add-assignment is `x => Console.WriteLine(...)` which is a lambda expression with parameter `x` and a body which calls `Console.WriteLine()`. Line three again is calling the function. The RHS is `AddBookwithISBN(56434)` which is a function call.

Comment: The value of `AddBookwithId` is a reference to a method. `AddBookwithId(15)` with parens is a *call* to the method, so the value of `AddBookwithId(15)` is whatever the method returns -- `void` in this case, nothing. You don't want to give the result of a call to the event handler; you want to tell the handler how to call the method itself. Hence you want to give it a reference to the method: `AddBookwithId`.

Answer (score 2):

The code below compiles...  The integer is expected to be passed when the Action is invoked.

```
       Action<int> AddBook = AddBookwithId; // Here is the error
       AddBook += x => Console.WriteLine("Added book with :{0}", x); // No compile error here
       AddBook += AddBookwithISBN;// of course, the same error here too.
```

Comment: Thanks @shaneRay . I am learning delegates in detail so I am getting confusion as I get more into it. Thanks for clarifying .

Answer (score 1):

```
    delegate void AddBook(int y);

    static void Main()
    {

        AddBook addBook;
        bool IsISBN = false;

        if (IsISBN)
        {
            addBook = AddBookwithISBN;
        }
        else
        {
            addBook = AddBookwithId;
        }
        addBook += x => Console.WriteLine("Added book with :{0}", x);
    }
    public static void AddBookwithId(int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Added Book to the shelf with the ID : {0} ", y);

    }

    public static void AddBookwithISBN(int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Added Book to the shelf  with the ISBN: {0} ", y + 2);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use [Lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)?
In fact, you have already used it in this line of code:

```
AddBook += x => Console.WriteLine("Added book with :{0}" , x ); // No compile error here
```

This will result in:

```
Action<int> AddBook = (x) => AddBookwithId(x); // Here is the error
AddBook += (x) => Console.WriteLine("Added book with :{0}" , x ); // No compile error here
AddBook += (x) => AddBookwithISBN(x);// of course, the same error here too.
```